# Unable to display PNG image from file in Gtk::Window

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I am having some trouble displaying a PNG file in a Gtk::Window. I tried creating a Gtk::Pixbuf from the file and then create a Gtk::Image using that. Then I tried adding the Gtk::Image to the Gtk::Window but all I'm getting a blank screen. What am I doing wrong?

```
class CMainWindow : public Gtk::ApplicationWindow
{
public:
    CMainWindow();
    ~CMainWindow();
};

CMainWindow::CMainWindow()
{
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pic = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file("image.png");
    Gtk::Image* img = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Image(pic));
    add(*img);
}

CMainWIndow::~CMainWindow() {}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,"org.gtkmm.examples.base");
    CMainWindow c;
    return app->run(c);
}
```

Comment: Strange, my search did not turn up a duplicate, even though this problem probably comes up a lot. Maybe people stumble over it the first dozen times, then start to remember more instinctively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `Gtk::Application::run()` will ensure that the `CMainWindow` is shown, it does not try to show all of its children. In your constructor, add a call to `img->show();`.

---

I recall seeing [a blog post](https://blog.gtk.org/2017/01/23/this-week-in-gtk-32/) reporting that the next version of GTK+ (hence also the next version of gtkmm, presumably) will change the default behavior so that widgets are shown by default. But for now, one has to remember to show them.

Comment: If you could ever remember the source of this "rumor", I would really like to take a look at it.

Comment: @BobMorane I found it. It's actually for GTK+ (not surprising, as gtkmm would not want to deviate from the underlying toolkit). The change was mentioned in the [GTK Development Blog](https://blog.gtk.org/2017/01/23/this-week-in-gtk-32/) back in 2017. I think I found the relevant commit in the GTK repository as well: [widget: Be visible by default](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/commit/fee788cd4ac109b9a1e967228f96de7ff2aa8baf). So it looks like version 4 will bring us widgets that are shown by default.